# Jquery load and manipulate image

Tags: jquery

I want to load an image into  div and manipulate it, e.g. resize and position the image.

```
var case_1_start.attr('src', 'images/case_1_1.jpg');  
    
     $('#case_1_btn').click(function() {
         $('#content_panel').load(case_1_start);
         //resize and reposition case_1_start
});
```

Comment: `var case_1_start.attr('src', 'images/case_1_1.jpg'); ` why `var`? What is your problem here? loading an image? Or reposition? What you mean by *"reposition"* and where's the code for it? Resize? Resize how? Please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.animate()` function to resize and reposition certain elements after loading them. The fiddle below loads an image (base64 data in this case), appends it to the `#image_placeholder` and then animates it.

https://jsfiddle.net/k61mt25r/4/